# kinect calibration- ImportError: No module named cv_bridge

Tags: ros, calibration, kinect, monocular-camera, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

UBUNTU 12.04 and FUERTE

I am following the tutorial on calibrating kinect at http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration

I am getting the following error

I have cv_bridge installed and I also rosmake it

sai@sai-HP-EliteBook-8460w:~$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw camera:=/camera/rgb --size 5x4 --square 0.0245
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 52, in 
from camera_calibration.calibrator import cvmat_iterator, MonoCalibrator, StereoCalibrator, ChessboardInfo
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 40, in

import cv_bridge

ImportError: No module named cv_bridge

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58088/kinect-calibration--importerror:-no-module-named-cv_bridge/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-03-14**:
Please specify your Ubuntu version and ROS version :-)

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-03-14**:
ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2013-03-14**:
Hi Sai, have you checked whether you included the cv_bridge in your manifest.xml?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-03-14**:
yeah it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the last version of CvBridge, some changes have been made. The tutorials on cv_bridge make no difference between includes in electric and Fuerte/Groovy, but there is some.

Thus, instead of

```
#include <cv_bridge/CvBridge.h>
```

You should try

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
```

Or the inverse ^^

As I'm not sure it'll really help, Let me know...

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-03-20**:
ok...i ll try it later but as of now, i m trying to run a script at https://svncvpr.in.tum.de/cvpr-ros-pkg/trunk/rgbd_benchmark/rgbd_benchmark_tools/src/rgbd_benchmark_tools/add_pointclouds_to_bagfile.py  and it gives me the exactly the same error No module names cv_bridge   ...Any help ?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-14**:
This issue with cv_bridge got solved when I added the path to cv_bridge.py to the python path of environment variables                                                     ....                                   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-14**:
If the same error occurs with image_geometry, then just remove import image_geometry. For calibrating ASUS replace the /camera/rgb/image_raw with /camera/rgb/image_mono in the rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator................